# Display current post after showing posts query result in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

In `sigle.php` page I need to display a list of post that belong to the category of the post and the I have to display the post content.

So I did a query to get the posts tat belong to the post category:

```
<?php
$cat = get_the_category();
query_posts('cat='.$cat[0]->cat_ID);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <li <?php echo get_the_ID() == get_query_var('p') ? 'class="current-menu-item"' : '';?>><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Now how can I retrive the current post data?
If I do like this

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php echo the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID());?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

I still display `query_posts`.

Comment: `query_posts` breaks the main query object which destroys the info of the currently viewed single post. **Never ever** use `query_posts`

Comment: Ok. So how can I do this? Have you any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved using `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts()`;

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query('cat='.$cat[0]->cat_ID);
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
        <li <?php echo get_the_ID() == get_query_var('p') ? 'class="current-menu-item"' : '';?>><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php echo get_the_title();?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```